# Do I2C wires and 120W (12V) power wires close together cause trouble?

Tags: power, i2c, wire, interference

I'm a beginner with electronics and I'm building my first solar powered robot. I now have a 50cm  long (1.6 feet) small pipe through which I want to put four wires; 2 for the power from the solar panel, and two for I2C to read some sensors. I've got two 100W solar panels, but I doubt I will ever get more than about 120W through it.

I don't know if the size of the wires matter, but currently I'm using 22AWG for the power, and 30AWG for the I2C.

I had some trouble before when the wires from the ESC to the BLDC motor and the PWM wires to a servo where touching eachother. Before I build this part of the robot I now wonder whether I will get into trouble if this I2C and the power are cramped together in the small pipe.

Does anybody know whether this will cause trouble (interference or something)?

Comment: Yes these do interfere. Use. Twisted pair and keep at right angles if possible.

Comment: What is the inside diameter of the pipe? Metal or plastic? There might be some tricks which could help.

Comment: @MarkLeavitt - The inside diameter of the pipe is 4.5mm and it's made of carbon fiber. I'm curious as to what kind of tricks you're talking about!

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 - Do you mean that I need to twist the I2C with eachother and the two power wires with eachother? And what do you mean with "the right angles"?

Comment: I was going to suggest using flat ribbon cable for the i2c signals, as well as sensor power and ground (i.e. don't connect the sensor directly to the solar panel + and -). But your pipe is probably too small.

Comment: @MarkLeavitt - Thanks for your thoughts. May I also ask what you think of the suggestion of Tony above, about twisting the pairs? And do you know what he means by "the right angle"?